# java/jackson - @JsonValue/@JsonCreator and null

Tags: java, json, null, jackson, wrapper

I have a `Value` class which holds a value:

```
public class Value {
    protected final Object value;

    @JsonValue
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Value(final Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This `Value` class is embedded as a field (amongst other fields) in a data class:

```
class Data {
    protected final Value value;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    ...

    @JsonCreator
    public Data(@JsonProperty("value") final Value value, ...) {
        this.value = value;
        ....
    }
}
```

When the input JSON has `null` for the `value` field of a `data` object (see below for example), `Data.value` is null. I would like to have `Data.value` set to `new Value(null)`. In other words, the data object must hold a non-null value object, which holds the null.

```
{
  "value" : null,
  ...
}
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this? I could ofcourse alter the constructor of `Data`, but I am wondering if Jackson could resolve this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom de-serializer and override the `getNullValue()` method according to your requirements e.g.

```
public final class InstantiateOnNullDeserializer
    extends JsonNodeDeserializer
{
    @Override
    public JsonNode getNullValue()
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(new Value(null), JsonNode.class);
        return node;
    }
}
```

and register it on the value field of your *Data* class

```
class Data {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = InstantiateOnNullDeserializer.class)
    protected final Value value;


    @JsonProperty("value")
    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }



    @JsonCreator
    public Data(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Note that you need to remove the `@JsonProperty("value")` to avoid argument type mismatch. By removing *JsonProperty* annotation you create a so-called "delegate creator",
Jackson will than first bind JSON into type of the argument, and then call a creator

Comment: Thanks. I'll write a custom deserialiser. Is this also valid for ctr? `public Data(@JsonProperty("value") @JsonDeserialize(using = InstantiateOnNullDeserializer.class) Value value) { ... }` and remove the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation from the getter. It makes more sense to me to link the deserialiser with the ctr/`@JsonCreator`.

Comment: in fact, it should be on the field, edited in the answer. I think that the deserializer will be applied only if set on field or accessor method. Remember to remove the @JsonProperty from the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this is possible without creating your own deserializer or modify the constructor (or `@JsonCreator`).

From [a good old thread in the Jackson User Group](http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/use-annotations-to-skip-levels):

> `@JsonProperty` does not support transformations, since the data binding is based on incremental parsing and does not have access to full tree representation.

So, in order to avoid a custom deserializer I would do something along the lines of:

```
@JsonCreator
public Data(@JsonProperty("value") final String value) {
    this.value = new Value(value);
}
```

Which is kind of the opposite of what you asked ;)